# EmailValidator usando apache.commons.validator no valida correctamente email

Tags: jsf

[image: Clase EmailValidator]
archivo index.xhtml donde especifico la etiqueta 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando ejecuto la aplicacion  e ingreso los datos y un email correcto y click en save el validator me dice que es un formato invalido

Cuando no ingreso email (cosa que no debería ser) el validator no lo detecta y pasa a la siguiente ventana de confirmación de datos.

¿Alguien que ha tenido este problema?

Comment: Hola @harpazo,  Por favor incluye el código directamente en la pregunta en lugar de dejarlo como imagen

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear tu propia validación usando expresiones regulares. **(No es lo más recomendable)**

Este sería una validación sencilla de un correo electrónico tipo xxxx@xxxx.xxx

```
@FacesValidator(value = "emailValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+@+\\w+\\.\\w+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher((CharSequence) value);
    HtmlInputText htmlInputText = (HtmlInputText) component;
    String label;

    if (htmlInputText.getLabel() == null || htmlInputText.getLabel().trim().equals("")) {
        label = htmlInputText.getId();
    } else {
        label = htmlInputText.getLabel();
    }

    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(label + ": not a valid email address");
        throw new ValidatorException(facesMessage);
    }
}
}
```

Y en la pagina algo parecido a esto:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Email Address:" for="email"/>
<h:inputText id="email" label="Email Address" required="true" value="#{registrationBean.email}">
    <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="email"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

isEmpty

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String str)
comprueba si un String is empty ("") o null.

 StringUtils.isEmpty(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isEmpty("")        = true
 StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false
 StringUtils.isEmpty("texto")   = false
 StringUtils.isEmpty("texto")   = false
```

isNotEmpty

```
public static boolean isNotEmpty(String str)

 StringUtils.isNotEmpty(null)      = false
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty("")        = false
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty(" ")       = true
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty("texto")   = true
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty("texto")   = true
```

.

Usted pone:

```
if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(email){
```

Esto hace que si `no esta vacio` entre en el if, y aplique lo que esta dentro, si no entiendo mal, esto es de lo que se queja, creo que podria solucionarlo usando por ejemplo:

```
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(email){
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes hacer la validación a nivel de bean de una vez (ya que se trata de un objeto a ser persistido).

```
class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable=false, length=16)
    @Size(min=4, max=16, message="La contraseña debe estar entre 4 y 16 dígitos")
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    @NotEmpty @Email // proveída por hibernate validator
    private String email;

    // constructores, getters y setters
}
```

En la vista:

```
<h:inputText id="email" label="Email address" value="#{registrationBean.user.email}" required="true" />
<h:message for="email" errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: blue" />
```